# $and condition doesn't work with three or more than three fields in springboot mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

```
@Document(collection = "formtype")
public class FormType {
    @Id
    @Field(value = "id")
    private Long formTypeId;  

    @Field(value = "formtypename")
    private String formTypeName;

@Field(value = "isdeleted")
private Boolean isDeleted = false;

 //with constructor and getter setter
}
```

I have written this query to find out the record of form type in which that `formTypeName` is not belong to that `formTypeId` and it's `isDeleted` is not equal to true.

Writing this query I get value as null even if that record is present.
     Please help me out!

```
 @Query("{ '$and': [ {'formTypeId':{$ne :?0}} , {formTypeName:'?0'} , {'isDeleted':{$ne : true}} ] }") FormType getformTypeToUpdate(Long formTypeId,String formTypeName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had `?0` enclosed within simple quotation, that may be misinterpreted by compiler. Also, it seems you only used `Long formTypeId` parameter for two conditions `formTypeId` and `formTypeName`.

Can you try:

```
@Query("{ '$and': [ { 'formTypeId': { $ne : ?0 } }, { 'formTypeName': ?1 }, { 'isDeleted': { $ne : true } } ] }") 
FormType getformTypeToUpdate(Long formTypeId, String formTypeName);
```

Comment: Why to use ?1 and what is the meaning of it in respective query?

Comment: You can use that notation to indicate which parameter from your method should spring use to replace in the string, so `?0` means formTypeId and `?1` means formTypeName